# app crashing because of animationDidStart selector is sent to objects that don't support it

Tags: ios7, iphone-5, caanimation

In my app i'm starting to see a new type of crash resulting from animationDidStart selector being sent to objects that don't support it like UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer and UIImageView. i started getting them on my new iphone 5s iOS 7.0.3 device (not sure if that is relevant to the crash). 
the call stacks are :

```
 Stack Trace: (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2de06e9b <redacted> + 154
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x381676c7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2de0a7b7 <redacted> + 202
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2de090af <redacted> + 706
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2dd57dc8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5   QuartzCore                          0x302183c1 <redacted> + 152
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3864c0af <redacted> + 22
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3864e9a9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 268
8   CoreFoundation                      0x2ddd15b1 <redacted> + 8
9   CoreFoundation                      0x2ddcfe7d <redacted> + 1308
10  CoreFoundation                      0x2dd3a471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
11  CoreFoundation                      0x2dd3a253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
12  GraphicsServices                    0x32a6e2eb GSEventRunModal + 138
13  UIKit                               0x305ef845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
14  spIM                                0x001398cd main + 116
15  libdyld.dylib                       0x38660ab7 <redacted> + 2
  )

 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView animationDidStart:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a3e5260'
 *** First throw call stack:
(0x2de06e83 0x381676c7 0x2de0a7b7 0x2de090af 0x2dd57dc8 0x302183c1 0x3864c0af 0x3864e9a9 0x2ddd15b1 0x2ddcfe7d 0x2dd3a471 0x2dd3a253 0x32a6e2eb 0x305ef845 0x1398cd 0x38660ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

and

```
   Stack Trace: (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2de06e9b <redacted> + 154
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x381676c7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2de0a7b7 <redacted> + 202
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2de090af <redacted> + 706
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2dd57dc8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5   QuartzCore                          0x302183c1 <redacted> + 152
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3864c0af <redacted> + 22
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3864e9a9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 268
8   CoreFoundation                      0x2ddd15b1 <redacted> + 8
9   CoreFoundation                      0x2ddcfe7d <redacted> + 1308
10  CoreFoundation                      0x2dd3a471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
11  CoreFoundation                      0x2dd3a253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
12  GraphicsServices                    0x32a6e2eb GSEventRunModal + 138
13  UIKit                               0x305ef845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
14  spIM                                0x001378cd main + 116
15  libdyld.dylib                       0x38660ab7 <redacted> + 2
 )
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer animationDidStart:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1abc2c80'
 *** First throw call stack:
 (0x2de06e83 0x381676c7 0x2de0a7b7 0x2de090af 0x2dd57dc8 0x302183c1 0x3864c0af 0x3864e9a9 0x2ddd15b1 0x2ddcfe7d 0x2dd3a471 0x2dd3a253 0x32a6e2eb 0x305ef845 0x1378cd 0x38660ab7)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```